# How not to pass a specific form field?

Tags: html

I'm writing a landing page to test a business idea.
For testing purpose, I want to write a Credit card number field, to see if the customer is actually ready to buy the product.

As it is only a test, I don't want this value to be submitted.
Actually for security purposes I don't even want this value to be sent in the request.

Is a separate form enough?

```
<form> Sensitive info</form>

<form>Info I want
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, only the elements from the one `form` will be sent (whichever one was submitted).

Alternatively, you could:

- mark the input as `disabled` (either from the start, or `onsubmit`)
- remove the `name` attribute of the input
- put another input later in the `form` with the same name (it will override the value of the first)

Comment: If its disabled they cannot use it and it will not be displayed?

Comment: Putting a second, hidden input, with the same name will work great.

Comment: @Chris - I would only set it to disabled on form submit (*excuse my inline javascript:* `<form onsubmit="this.myfield.disabled = true">`)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that will work.